# JsonPath - with one DocumentContext how can I query with both the default configuration and Option.AS_PATH_LIST?

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have a JSON file that I need to do multiple queries on. So I create a single DocumentContext (so I have 1 parse) to the call read() on.

However, in some cases I want the returned results to be Option.AS_PATH_LIST and others I want the default. Is there a way to do this?

Or do I need to build 2 DocumentContext objects?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1):

If you compile a JsonPath then you can pass a configuration to the read method as seen [here](http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.4.0/com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.html#read-java.lang.Object-com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration-) in the javadoc.

```
String json = "{\"a\":\"b\"}";
Object parse = Configuration.defaultConfiguration()
  .jsonProvider()
  .parse(json);
JsonPath path = JsonPath.compile("$.a");
System.out.println(path.read(parse, Configuration.builder().options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build()));
System.out.println(path.read(parse));
```

Comment: This looks good but point of clarification please. I switched over to using DocumentContext.read(query). You show compiling the query and then using path.read(parse). What is the purpose of each approach? (I'm good with your approach, I just want to understand the library better.)

Comment: It looks like the DocumentContext gives you some benefits like caching compiled json paths and it can handle json-to-object mapping for you. It's a higher level interface and hides a few details of how to use the paths.

The downside is that it doesn't look like there is a way to alter the configuration of the context, it's immutable. You aren't given access to the full set of methods on JsonPath.

Better depends on your needs, the DocumentContext api looks like it's simpler and exposes you to less classes. Using compiled JsonPaths gives you full control.